# Terminate RL DDPG episode if ode solver do not have a solution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, reinforcement-learning, ode, ddpg

I am building an LQR type controller using RL DDPG in MATLAB. I had a question.
I am stepping the environment using ode15s solver (my environment is a system of DAEs which I am solving using ode15s). I want to terminate the episode if for any action at the beginning, the ode15s is not able to solve the environment. How can I do it? Any help will highly be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: This is not really an SO question. Can you try out the "Events" functionality? Terminate the computation if some function of the state changes its sign?